# ZF2 - How to pass config array to base test case class

Tags: zend-framework2

When using `AbstractControllerTestCase` (or it's subclasses) you get a convenient method `setApplicationConfig()` that let's you pass an array similar to `config/application.config.php`, so that you include only the modules you need in order to test.

How do you pass the array that goes into `config/autoload/global.php` to `AbstractControllerTestCase`?

PS: if it helps, I'm trying to pass a custom ORM connection that uses SQLite

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make separate config files to be used when testing and load those inside your test controller.

for example;

```
copy config/application.config.php to config/application.config.test.php
```

Make a small change to allow us to load separate test config files without touching the global config files used by the production application.

```
 'config_glob_paths' => array(realpath(__DIR__) . '/autoload/{,*.}{global,test}.php'),
```

This will allow us to override any config values we need  as the test config files are loaded after the usual global config files. We can now please any test specific configureation inside test.php, anything.test.php etc.

now you can copy

```
autoload/global.php to autoload/test.php
```

You can now change config items and these will override those inside global.php

autoload/test.php

```
<?php
return array(
'db' => array(
    'driver'    => 'Pdo',
    'dsn' => 'sqlite:' . __DIR__ .'/../../data/testing.sqlite',
    //'dsn'       => 'mysql:dbname=somedatabase;host=localhost',
    'username'  => 'dbuser',
    'password'  => 'passwordgoeshere',
),
```

You could also change the driver to use SQL lite or what ever your require to run your tests.

Now you just need to make your test controllers load our new application config file:

```
use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;

class ExampleTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setApplicationConfig(
           include __DIR__ . '/../../config/application.config.test.php'
        );
    }
```

This allows you to keep all your test configuration separate to your main application config settings.

Comment: This was my first approach, but I'd rather have a `TestConfig` class that will provide both `application.config.php` and `global.php` values through static methods like `TestConfig::getConfiguration()`.

Comment: Why? this gets you nothing extra. you will notice the config files return an array so you can easily use this in a class. example $myArray = include 'some.config.php';
this will allow u to return data in those files and/or merge inside your class.

Comment: Mostly for the sake of having a clean test directory structure

Comment: None of the  suggested files would be in the test directory. I think u need to update your question as it's nothing like what you're asking here =)